# Detect when an image enters a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a maze game, and I want to detect when the image following the cursor reaches a certain div, the finishing point. I have the image following the mouse, and I have the container that the image will be in. When the image reaches the div, I want something to trigger, lets say an alert. How can I achieve this?

```js
  

    var startMove;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var DIFF_SNAP = 10;
  var DIFF_UNSNAP = 100;
  var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
  var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
  if (!startMove && Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_SNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_SNAP) {
    startMove = true;
    $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
  } else if (startMove && !(Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_UNSNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_UNSNAP)) {
    startMove = false;
  }
  if (startMove) {
    $("#image").css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
  } else {
    $('html').addClass('showCursor');
  }
});

$(document).mouseleave(function() {
  startMove = false;
})
```

```css
    
        html {cursor: none;}
    html.showCursor{cursor: default;}
    #image{
    position:absolute;
    width:25px;
    height:auto;
    }
div{
margin-left: 500px;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
    <img id="image" src="http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/mac-osx-arrow-cursor.png"/>
<div></div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3x7cgLdr/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a flag called startMove that is active whenever the cursor is dragged, use the mouseenter event on the target div as follows:

```
var startMove;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
    var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
    if(difLeft < 10 && difLeft > -10 && difTop < 10 && difTop > -10 ){
      startMove = true;
      $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
    }
    if(startMove){
        $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    }
    else{
        $('html').addClass('showCursor');
    }
});

$(document).mouseleave(function(){
    startMove = false;
})

$("#drop").mouseenter(function(){
 if(startMove)
   alert("Success");
});
```

.

```
<img id="image" src="http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/mac-osx-arrow-cursor.png"/>

<div id="drop">
</div>
```

.

```
html {cursor: none;}
html.showCursor{cursor: default;}
#image{
position:absolute;
width:25px;
z-index: 100;
height:auto;
}

#drop{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  position: absolute;
  left:200px;
  top: 300px;
  z-index:99
}
```

see a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hycd913y/

Answer (score 1):

```
     if ($('#TargetDiv').is(':hover')) {
     // alert('hello');
     $("#image").addClass("red");
     }else{
     $("#image").removeClass("red");
    }
```

Using this .is() function with :hover selector inside the

```
if(startMove){

    }
```

Section simply does that without any hassle the is() function Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

[.is() function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```js
var startMove;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
  var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
  if (difLeft < 10 && difLeft > -10 && difTop < 10 && difTop > -10) {
    startMove = true;
    $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
  }
  if (startMove) {
    $("#image").css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    if ($('#TargetDiv').is(':hover')) {
      // alert('hello');
      $("#image").addClass("red");
    } else {
      $("#image").removeClass("red");
    }
  } else {
    $('html').addClass('showCursor');
  }
});

$(document).mouseleave(function() {
  startMove = false;
})
```

```css
html {
  cursor: none;
}
html.showCursor {
  cursor: default;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: auto;
}
#TargetDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/mac-osx-arrow-cursor.png" />


<div id="TargetDiv">

</div>
```

I have added a class to set border red to the div when it hovers on the div with mouse and cursor image superimposed that is startMove="true".And removes when it is not hovered .I have commented the alert box;You can turn it on if you want